# Anymote protocol server implementation

Tags: android, google-tv, anymote

I am trying to implement a server side for anymote protocol. I want to design it in a way that the current avilable applications(Google TV remote)in the market can be directly used with it. Is there any reference code available for the same ??

Also the documentation available at https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/anymote
does not seem to suffice the requirements to start the development. Is there any other requirement specific doc whihc can be used to design this server.

Any clue or starting point would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 parts you need to implement on the server:

1. A discovery service that will broadcast the device information on the local network. Look at the client side logic to see how this needs to be done: https://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/BroadcastDiscoveryClient.java
2. You also need to implement the pairing protocol on the server to allow remote devices to be paired with the server device (typically using a PIN): https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/pairing
3. You need to implement the Anymote protocol on the server. The anymote service would need to run as a system service since it needs to inject key and touch events into the Android system.

For both the pairing and Anymote protocols there are client code available that could be modified to implement a server. The discovery part could just be a simple Android service that broadcasts the right device information in a thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Leon. As per my understanding :            Point 1 and 2, The connection establisment part comes under Google TV pairing protocol and the complete server code for this appears to be available. So this should not worry me much.Please correct me if I am wrong. 
As for point 3, I plan to put the service in middleware in C++. Is that okie ??

Comment: Google TV does not provide an NDK, so 3 would have to be in Android.

Comment: @LeonNicholls Nice answer sir, can you please post the sample code for server side.